# Ultrawidescreen monitor with aspect ratio that matches anamorphic films

Tags: monitors

I am looking for an ultrawidescreen monitor with an aspect ratio that exactly matches the most common anamorphic aspect ratio of 2.39:1 used in many films, in order to view this type of content without extraneous black bars on the top and bottom of the screen.

Is there any monitor that matches these specifications? If there are multiple such monitors, higher resolutions, color accuracy, and refresh rates are preferred.

Comment: Why that specific ratio? It's not even the most common cinematic ratio. 1.85:1 ia just as prevalent. if you're prepared to accept 21:9 as a bit of a compromise [technically 2.37:1], google can find a lot of those. Whatever you get, unless you live on a diet of only 2.39:1 movies, you're going to have to black bar or zoom most of the time.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I will get another one with a 1.85:1 aspect ratio, but I thought that the wider one would be a bit harder.